# ¿Cómo recobrar un arreglo para usarlo en otra clase, dentro de una función en esa clase?

Tags: java, array, clase

Me gustaría saber como puedo recobrar el arreglo bidimensional **cosas** declarado en el código para usarlo en la función **drawAgeGroup1** la cual tengo declarada en una clase diferente pero que esta dentro del mismo paquete.

En la clase de ***lectura*** se lee un archivo y voy guardando los datos en el arreglo **cosas**, y en la función **drawAgeGroup1** quiero obtener todos los valores de cosas[i][1] para generar un contador de los niveles de edad que esta leyendo la clase ***lectura***.

La variable *r* la estaría usando rutinariamente pero cambiando el indice de la fila del arreglo cosas, pero no tengo idea de como poder mandarla a llamar o usarla.
Soy nueva en esto.

Les dejo el código:

```
public class lectura {
    public static String leer(String nombre) {
        try {
            File f;
            FileReader lectorArchivo;
            f= new File(nombre);
            lectorArchivo = new FileReader(f);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(lectorArchivo);
            String l = "";
            String aux = "";
            int cuentolinea = 0;
            while(true) {
                aux = br.readLine();
                int numTokens = 0;
                if(aux!=null) {
                    l = l + aux;
                    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer (aux);
                    while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
                        String s2 = st.nextToken();
                        String cosas [][] = new String [1088][5];
                        cosas [cuentolinea][numTokens] = s2;
                        numTokens++;
                    }
                } else {
                    break;
                }
                cuentolinea++;
            }
            br.close();
            lectorArchivo.close();
            return l;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Error:"+e.getMessage());
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

y la otra clase es la siguiente:

```
public class SimulatorY {
private void drawAgeGroup1(){
        double r = ?? //aqui debo recobrar el cosas[i][1]
        if(r >= Pr_CHILD & r <= Pr_YOUNG){Age_Group = "young"; youngCount++;}
        else if(r > Pr_YOUNG & r <= Pr_ADULT){Age_Group = "adult"; adultCount++;}
        else{Age_Group = "old"; oldCount++;}
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cambia el tipo del método leer de String a [][] String así en lugar de hacer un return null escribe un `return cosas;`

```
public class lectura {
public static String [] [] leer(String nombre) {
    try {
        File f;
        FileReader lectorArchivo;
        f= new File(nombre);
        lectorArchivo = new FileReader(f);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(lectorArchivo);
        String l = "";
        String aux = "";
        int cuentolinea = 0;
        while(true) {
            aux = br.readLine();
            int numTokens = 0;
            if(aux!=null) {
                l = l + aux;
                StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer (aux);
                while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
                    String s2 = st.nextToken();
                    String cosas [][] = new String [1088][5];
                    cosas [cuentolinea][numTokens] = s2;
                    numTokens++;
                }
            } else {
                break;
            }
            cuentolinea++;
        }
        br.close();
        lectorArchivo.close();
        return cosas;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Error:"+e.getMessage());
    }
    return null;
}
```

y en la clase SimulatorY antes de usar el double r recibe el arreglo de la otra clase

```
public class SimulatorY {
private void drawAgeGroup1(){
        //aquí obtendrás la matriz cosas completa de esta manera podrás manipularla según tus necesidades
        String [][] cosas = lectura.leer(nombre)
        double r = ?? //aqui debo recobrar el cosas[i][1]
        if(r >= Pr_CHILD & r <= Pr_YOUNG){Age_Group = "young"; youngCount++;}
        else if(r > Pr_YOUNG & r <= Pr_ADULT){Age_Group = "adult"; adultCount++;}
        else{Age_Group = "old"; oldCount++;}
    }
```

asi de esta manera podras iterar el contenido del arreglo bidimensional y podras usarlo de acuerdo a tus necesidades, espero haber sido de ayuda. saludos.

Comment: Me ayudo mucho lo que dijiste y ya solo en la case SimulatorY hice la converción de string a double.

Gracias